# Creating an Uninstaller for my program?

Tags: vb.net, installation, uninstallation

I am preparing to publish my software. I have created my own custom installer/uninstaller. I was wondering how I can have the uninstaller appear in "Programs and Features" under "Uninstall a program."

Thanks in advance

Comment: This support is often provided by a "VS Setup Project" (see also "WiX" and "MSI") or 3rd-party installer/packager tool such as InstallShield. There is a special place in the registry where keys are added, such that Windows knows what to list in the Installed Programs and what to launch on a user action.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest tool to create a setup is Inno setup. The normal and recommended delivery method is using Windows Installer, but this technology is quite involved to deal with. If your tool is simple, perhaps just have a look at Inno setup and see if it gets the job done quickly for you. It's capable of installing and registering your application in add / remove programs.

Here is another thread: [What to use for creating a quick and light setup file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684538/what-to-use-for-creating-a-quick-and-light-setup-file?rq=1)

Comment: So I cannot use my own installer/uninstaller? I already have both developed and working very well, I just need a way to have the uninstaller show in add/remove programs. I may exclude it from add/remove programs if I can't have it there, but have a shortcut to it in the start menu. Everything else is straight forward.

I want to use my own installer as it allows for the files to be downloaded from my web server, that way users can have the latest version and all works well.